# Send HTTP Post Request PHP

Tags: php, api, steam

I try use the Steam API for cancel a trade offer. Following this: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService#CancelTradeOffer_.28v1.29

I need pass the tradeofferid with an HTTP Post request. I make this but the tradeoffer don't cancel:

```
    function RechazarOferta($tradeid)
{
    $data = array('tradeofferid' => $tradeid);
    $trade = array('tradeofferid' => $tradeid, 'language' => 'english');

    $url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/CancelTradeOffer/v1/?key=C9786993763535D16XXXXXXXXX&'.http_build_query($trade);

    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $return = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    var_dump($return);
}
```

Any solution or better form to make an HTTP Post request?

Answer (score 2):

Curl is very ugly and old.
Try [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 
   'https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/CancelTradeOffer/v1', 
   ['query' => [
       'key' =>'C9786993763535D16XXXXXXXXX',
       'tradeofferid' => $tradeid, 
       'language' => 'english']
   ]
);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "200"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for do that, please test:

```
$url = 'https://yourweb.com';
$body = 'var1=1&var2=2';

$result = get_data($url, $body);

function get_data($url, $body)
{
    //$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    $ch      = curl_init();
    $timeout = 7;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This don't work, they return me the same that my function, only a "response:".

Comment: Hi, I update the answer with support for https, only copied the line with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);